# LLBLGen Pro v2.6 designer issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, orm, llblgenpro

How do you delete more than one entity at the same time in the designer Entities list. it seems that the designer interface only allows the selection of 1 entity at a time....

This is frustrating, is this possible? Or even deleting all entities?

Thanks

Regards

Luis

Comment: Try your question here: http://www.llblgen.com/tinyforum/.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I am having the same issue - no multi-select in the project explorer.

Comment: I started a thread here - http://www.llblgen.com/TinyForum/Messages.aspx?ThreadID=18246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the support team:

> Sorry, once they're added to the project, the only way to remove them is one at a time.
>   Matt